# How to resolve memory issue in Eclipse Juno 23.0?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

Please anyone help me to resolve memory issues in Eclipse Juno. After I updated 22.6.0 to 23.0. Every 10 seconds I'm getting PermGem java heap memory issue. Especially It's happening on layout file changes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you see java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space errors, you need to increase the permanent generation space available to Eclipse. 
Open your eclipse.ini file and change parameters
 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
 -Xms128m
 -Xmx512m

Answer (score 0):

Please post your hardware specs. Anyway, it is important that you increase the heap size to its optimal size, please see table below:

System memory (physical)                          Optimal heap size 
         512 MB                                                   256 MB
                      
         1 GB                                                        512 MB

         1. 5 GB                                                  768 MB

         2+ GB                                                    1024 MB

You can check this [post](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F) for your reference to increase heap size for Eclipse.